# OpenLayers: can't render two tiff files almost the same

Tags: openlayers

I have created this codesandbox example, in which I render without any style a tiff:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-test-aspect-kriw38?file=/main.js

[image]

The tiff source is this https://andy-aws.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/input.tiff

If I replace it with a very similar tiff (https://andy-aws.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/sample_dnw_byte.tiff) I have no rendering.

I'm sure it's an error of mine, but I don't understand what it is.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the negative height of the tiles.

I can read it using:

```
source.getView().then(() => {console.log(source.getTileGrid())});
```

I have regenerated again the source using gdalwarp, and I have now the right dimensions.

In the source tif, I had wrong pixels size.